# Help me (dis)prove a conjecture about square numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, square-numbers, conjectures

Let $S=k*m+p$ be any number where $k,m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $p$ is a prime number.

My claim is the following:

There exists some nondecreasing function $f:\mathbb{N}\mapsto\mathbb{N}$ with $f(m)\to\infty$ and $\frac{f(m)}{m}\to 0$ for $m\to\infty$, such that for **any** $m\in\mathbb{N}$ the **number of primes** that satisfy

- $p\leq f(m)$ and
- for at least one value of $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $S$ is a square number that is coprime to $m$

is less than some constant $\Phi\in\mathbb{N}$.

I posted this about an hour ago but it was written poorly with many mistakes and I hope that this is a much better way of presentation.

My guess is that $\Phi$ could be huge, if the claim holds true. Although I think that there is probably a counter example that I am not seeing. If there is not, then I would suspect $f(m)=log(m)$ defined for $m\geq T$ for some $T\in\mathbb{N}$ to be a candidate for this kind of slowly growing function.

Comment: $2$ is a square $\pmod q$ for any odd  prime $q$ of the form $q=8n\pm 1$ for some natural number $n$.  So, take $p=2$ and just look at the case where $m$ is an odd prime of that form. We can always find a $k$ that works in that case (infinitely many, actually) and the number of such $S$ grows to infinity.

Comment: @lulu I don't know if I misunderstand something. I should have pointed out that multiple values for $k$ do not count. It is about the values for $p$. Therefore I edited the claim.

Comment: Even if you only care about $p$, choose $m$ such that $2,3,5,7, 11, 13, 17, \cdots$ are squares $\pmod m$  Such an $m$ always exists (Chinese Remainder Theorem).